# How can I pass variables from the command prompt into my java program

Tags: java, io, inputstream

Is there a way to read data from the command prompt? I have a java program that relies on 4 input variables from an outside source. These variables are returned to the command prompt after I run a javascript program but i need a way to pass these variables from the command prompt into my java program, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean as command line parameters or as standard input?

Comment: [Command-Line Arguments - The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

Comment: Of course you can, either trivially through `main`'s parameter, or cleverly, using one of any of several command line parsing libraries.

Comment: (Also, JavaScript != Java, but someone beat me to tag removal.)

Comment: as standard input into an array. and I know java and javascript are different, im using a javascript to get the data from the url, parse, and return the data to my java program which will take the cleaned up data and use it. I just have no idea how to get the data returned from the javascript into my java program

Answer (score 2):

While executing java program pass the parameters and all the parameters should be separated by space.

**java programName parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 parameter4**

This parameters would be available in your main method argument

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     //This args array would be containing all four values, i.e. its length would be 4 and you easily iterate values.
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Argument " + i + " is " + args[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link:

Command-Line Arguments - The Java™ Tutorials : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

shared by @BackSlash.

It has all the content which would help you to clear all your doubts.
The content from the link is quoted below:

> **Displaying Command-Line Arguments passed by user from command-line to a Java program**
>
> The following example displays each of its command-line arguments on a
>   line by itself:
>
> ```
> public class DisplayCommandLineParameters {
>     public static void main (String[] args) {
>         for (String s: args) {
>             System.out.println(s);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **To compile the program:**   From the Command Prompt, navigate to the directory containing your .java file, say C:\test, by typing the cd
>   command below.
>
> C:\Users\username>**cd c:\test**
>   C:\test>
>
> Assuming the file, say DisplayCommandLineParameters.java, is in the
>   current working directory, type the javac command below to compile it.
>
> C:\test>**javac DisplayCommandLineParameters.java**
>   C:\test>
>
> If everything went well, you should see no error messages.
>
> **To run the program:**   The following example shows how a user might run the class.
>
> C:\test>**java DisplayCommandLineParameters Hello Java World**
>
> **Output:**
>   Hello
>   Java
>   World
>
> Note that the application displays each word — Hello, Java and World —
>   on a line by itself. This is because the space character separates
>   command-line arguments.
>
> To have Hello, Java and World interpreted as a single argument, the
>   user would join them by enclosing them within quotation marks.
>
> C:\test>**java DisplayCommandLineParameters "Hello Java World"**
>
> **Output:**   Hello Java World

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Okay.. as you suggested.. I'm quoting the answer mentioned in the link and updating the answer.